# I changed my name then I delete Minecraft in %appdata% then can't log back in with my original e-mail and password again!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If you sees this pleaseeeeee help me cause it's been a while and I do not want to lose my server ranks and money, please help. I will thank you. :'(

Comment: What exactly is happening when you try to log in? Can you log in on minecraft.net?

Answer (score 1):

Normally the server identifies you by requesting a unique UUID that belongs to your account from Mojangs login server. There is no problem to reinstall your Minecraft client.

Be sure that you have purchased a original version of the game from Mojang and login with the same account. Otherwise there might be a problem.